# Make useEffect hook run before rendering the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I've got a useEffect hook that I use in my App.js file. It puts data into redux store that I need to use in my App. But it renders before the useEffect runs, therefore the data is undefined. The useEffect then runs correctly.
I need useEffect to run before anything gets rendered. How could I do that? Or what other solution should I use? I have tried removing the useEffect completely and just running the action, but that results in it running endlessly.
This is my code:

```
function App() {
  const app = useSelector(state => state.app);
  const auth = useSelector(state => state.auth);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(authActions.checkUser());
  }, [dispatch]);

  console.log(auth.user); //undefined

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={!app.theme ? darkTheme : theme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <React.Fragment>
        {/* TODO: Display drawer only when logged in */}
        {/* <Drawer></Drawer> */}
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
          <Route exact path="/dashboard">
            <Dashboard user={auth.user} /> //auth.user is undefined when this gets rendered
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
        </Switch>
      </React.Fragment>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

```
export const checkUser = () => async dispatch => {
  let token = localStorage.getItem("auth-token");
  if (token === null) {
    localStorage.setItem("auth-token", "");
    token = "";
  }
  const tokenRes = await Axios.post("http://localhost:5000/users/tokenIsValid", null, {
    headers: { "x-auth-token": token }
  });
  if (tokenRes.data) {
    const userRes = await Axios.get("http://localhost:5000/users/", {
      headers: { "x-auth-token": token }
    });
    dispatch({
      type: CHECK_USER,
      token,
      user: userRes.data
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I need useEffect to run before anything gets rendered. How could I do
> that?

You cannot make `useEffect` run *before* the initial render.

Just like `componentDidMount` in class components runs *after* the initial render, `useEffect` runs *after* the initial render and then its execution depends on whether you pass the second argument, i.e. dependency array to `useEffect` hook.

> what other solution should I use?

You can conditionally render the content by making sure that you render the asynchronously fetched data *only* after it is available.

```
return (
   { auth ? <render content> : null}
);
```

or

```
return (
   { auth && <render content> }
);
```

**P.S:** angle brackets `< or >` are not included in the syntax. They are just there as a placeholder for the content that you need to render.

For details, see: [React - Conditional Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

Comment: Thanks, this works, but obviously, there's a slight delay before the render content displays. How could I prevent this delay?

Comment: While the data is loading, you could render some kind of loading spinner to indicate that data is being loaded.

Answer (score 1):

## Alternative

You can use `useMemo`, which doesn't wait for `re-render`. It will execute same way based on dependencies like useEffect too.

```
useMemo(()=>{
    doSomething() //Doesn't want until render is completed 
}, [dep1, dep2])
```