# UseEffect dosen't trigger setState when using sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hey I've go a problem with this code.

```
const [itemsCart, setCart] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    (async function (){
      const buffer = await JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem("itemsCart"))
      setCart(buffer);
      console.log(buffer);
      console.log(itemsCart);
    })()
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.sessionStorage.setItem("itemsCart", JSON.stringify(itemsCart));
  }, [itemsCart]);
```

The buffer gets the data, the state variable dosen't. I assume there must be a problem with synchronization however I'm not able to fix that.
The output:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQ8QU.png)

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. You're using `async` but there is no `await`. You read from `session.itemsCart` and write it back. What exactly are you expecting this code to do? Maybe move `console.log(itemsCart);` into the bottom `useEffect`? The top `useEffect` will only ever run once, the buttom one will run every time `itemsCart` cart changes.

Comment: Why you are using async and await for getting sessionValue?

Comment: Logging a state directly after setting it will display the previous value, since state is set asynchronously and the value won't be updated yet.

Comment: the first version looked like this ` const [itemsCart, setCart] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const buffer = JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem("itemsCart"))
    setCart(buffer);
    console.log(buffer);
    console.log(itemsCart);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.sessionStorage.setItem("itemsCart", JSON.stringify(itemsCart));
  }, [itemsCart]);` just it didnt work I started to try to change everything.

Answer (score -1):

This happens because react will wait until all script in useEffect is called and after that, setState will trigger rerender. Because there can be multiple setStates and we want to rerender it only once. That means, you are logging old value in `console.log(itemsCart)` before its actually there after rerender.

You can logi it with second `useEffect` before updating sessionStorage and you will see, that state is changed. Or you can create new useEffect for this

```
useEffect(()=>{
 console.log(itemsCart)
},[itemsCart]);
```

Comment: I changed it to the following
`const [itemsCart, setCart] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const buffer = JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem("itemsCart"))
    setCart(buffer);
    console.log(buffer);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(itemsCart);
    window.sessionStorage.setItem("itemsCart", JSON.stringify(itemsCart));
  }, [itemsCart]);`
still the same result. the state variable returns an empty array.

Answer (score -1):

this works:

```
const [itemsCart, setCart] = useState(JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("itemsCart")));

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(itemsCart);
    window.localStorage.setItem("itemsCart", JSON.stringify(itemsCart));
  }, [itemsCart]);
```

Answer (score -1):

To run the second `useEffect()`, `itemsCart` needs to be modified before via useState(). I can't see in your first `useEffect()` when you call `setItemsCart()`.

Answer (score -1):

This question is not correct and the approach to solve the problem is not correct as well(whatever problem you are trying to solve).
React has different design.

You are trying to get the items and then set them once you get it using useEffect.

The best approach would be to pass your array as a prop from higher order component and then use your useEffect once it has been triggered by dependencies(passed prop)

[Make useEffect hook run before rendering the component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63967956/make-useeffect-hook-run-before-rendering-the-component)